# Django/VueJS/PostgreSQL adding leading/trailing whitespace tabs

Tags: html, css, django, vue.js, vue-material

I have a text-field in Django I'm maintaining using Django-admin that requires preservation of white-space. As a result I'm wrapping it in a `<pre> </pre>` tag to do this when rendering using `vueJS` and `vue-material`.

The whitespace appears to be retained when using this method, and when looking at the `descrip` field of my model manually in `python manage.py shell` the whitespace is indeed stored in my db.

[image: whitespace showing up in model field in django shell.]

However, for some reason there is a mysterious leading white-space tab both at the beginning and end of my HTML when rendered, shown here:

[image: rendered html with added white space]

And showing up in the HTML here:

[image: rendered html showing additional markup with whitespace]

Code snippets:

**relevant html and css**

```
  <md-layout md-column md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="55"
     md-flex-medium="70" md-flex-large="80" id="summary_block">
    <md-layout >
      <pre class="md-body">
         [[ product.descrip ]]
      </pre>
    </md-layout>
  </md-layout>

#summary_block > div.md-layout > pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Could this be a `postgres` issue? If so why wouldn't the whitespace show up when looking at `object.descrip` in the python shell?

I'm using `postgres`, `vuejs`, `django` v `1.10`, `python 3.5` and `vue-material` if any/all of that helps.

Comment: Using any CSS framework like bootstrap?

Comment: just `vue-material`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `white-space: pre-wrap;`  who causes this behavior.

Instead try: `white-space: normal;`

[Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: that did it! `pre-line` was what i was looking for. thanks very much!